# Django template: {% if 5 in ['4', '3', '5'] %} doesn't work

Tags: python, django

form.tickets.value has the values `['29', '4', '7']`
ticket_id has values such as 5, 3, 7 etc.

Now I want to print YES if 7 exist in the list. But it always says 'No'. Anyone can tell me why?

```
{% if ticket_id in form.tickets.value %}
    YES
{% else %}
    {{ ticket_id }} not in {{ form.tickets.value }}
{% endif %}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: In Python/Django template language, the integer `7` is not equal to the string `'7'`.

Comment: Do you know how I can change that in the template?

Comment: `5` is not in `['4', '3', '5']` but `'5'` is.

Comment: Okay, I understand. My problem is I get `ticket_id` from this for loop `{% for ticket_id, ticket_label in form.tickets.field.choices %}`. I am not sure how to fix that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, the *type* of the variable matters. You are comparing an integer to a list of strings. Since the types differ, the values will **never** be equal (even though they "look" the same).

You could either convert your lists to lists of integers instead of strings, or convert the integer you are comparing to a string. Here's an example of the latter, using one of Django's built-in template filters:

```
{% if ticket_id|stringformat:"s" in form.tickets.value %}
```

Comment: I actually just realised that I have to convert it the other way around. Reason is that my UpdateView gives me this format back: 29 in [29, 28]

That explains why it worked there. How would you convert ['4', '3', '5'] into [4, 3, 5]?

Comment: Easy solution: 
 <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="{{ form.tickets.html_name }}"
                value={{ ticket_id }}

Before I wrote value="{{ ticket_id }}" That was the reason it was a String